# Freezing Android APK version for older SDKs

Tags: android

I understand how multiple APKs work on Google Play, but so far I've supported a single APK for V7 (2.1) and up. I'd like to start using Android 3.x-4.x+ features that could be more difficult to make backwards compatible, and I wouldn't mind not having to build in that growing compatibility library. But I still want to make the product available to Android 2.x users, even though that version will be "frozen" and not receive future product enhancements.

So how should this best be done? I could use the basic multiple-APK approach, but then users of 2.x devices might see things in the product description that are not in the APK that they would be installing. But would the version number show up correctly based on the APK that matches the user's device?

Any other ideas from someone who's done this?